# Exclusion of specific effect

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, hypothesis-testing, econometrics

I have the following problem:

I was asked prepare a quick equation that would be used to roughly calibrate forecast of defaults in economy that we subscribe to, to our company's defaults.

It will be more a form of calibration so in the future the resulting equation could be applied on the actual economic predictions prepared by professional academic sources (for example apply that equation on 2022 predictions that economists made), rather than pure prediction itself.

Initially I regressed our historical defaults on historical default rates in local economy. Yet, they would surely not have a proportional relationship, due to the firm's growth and customer base changing drastically past 2 years (company was started 4 years ago).

Is there any clever to train the model to exclude firm-specific effect in such calibration (ie isolate economic-driven impact and not volatile company's past), other than adding some fix effect variables?